# fetch datetime from a Excel sheet through OleDbDataAdapter

Tags: c#, excel, datetime, csv, oledb

i am facing a problem when i fetch datetime column from Excel containing CSV format values then its show null because the value on datetime column is like 50:48:12 (HH:MM:SS), but when the value is under datetime range like 23:12:32 then its working perfect...

i want to fetch the Excel column with any datetime value
e.g if the value is 50:48:12 then i got the same value on Query result

my snap code is below
my OleDbDataAdapter connection is 
`string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
              + "Data Source=\"" + dir + "\\\";"
              + "Extended Properties=\"text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited\"";`

My query is 
`string query = "SELECT * FROM " + file;`

```
OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connString);

        try
        {
            //fill the DataTable
            dAdapter.Fill(dTable);
        }
```

Values In Excel Sheet is
104:24:54
22:12:34
720:01:00

and if i open dataTable then

1. value in dTable.Tables[0].Rows[0] is
   null
2. value in dTable.Tables[0].Rows[1] is
   10:12:34 PM
3. value in dTable.Tables[0].Rows[2] is
   null

please give me any solution

Answer (score 0):

Your date values are not captured in a valid format 104:24:54 & 720:01:00. 22:12:34 is the only valid one. Why are the other value higher than 24.00.00?

Comment: actually the value of date is set by another software, and i have to export that table through Excel sheet. i knew that this format is not write, but i have to fetch the date